# How worried should I be about mistakes in my CV after submitting my grad school applications?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions

I would appreciate your input so much! I am applying to PhD programs in Sociology and Education, and I noticed two mistakes in my CV after submitting my applications.

1. I included one of my positions in the wrong chronological order. The dates and information are correct, it is just in the wrong order (a 2019 Summer position listed after an October 2019 position). Do you think this is a big deal?
2. I accidentally said I completed a research project in 2023 instead of 2020. I listed the name of the school for this project, and my transcripts show I graduated from this school in 2020, so I think whoever reads it can see it’s an honest mistake, but I’m still worrying it can be confusing.

The worst part is, I have already contacted admissions offices about an incorrect date on my CV (I don’t know what it is with dates that I made so many mistakes!) and some of them let me upload an updated version. I’m really kicking myself for not noticing these additional mistakes until now. I really don’t want to contact them again and seem careless or even annoying, so I am wondering if I should just let it go.

For additional context: I have anxiety and it is REALLY hard to not overthink things like these.

Comment: Let it go, that’s all, and proofread better next time round.

Comment: Neither of those seem to be blocking issues. Relax. Submit a correction if possible.

Answer (score -1):

I think the impact is minimal. If you have good GPA in a good university, I will still consider you, at most asking for clarification. It won't change my decision on proceeding your case or not.